# python version 3: how to ask user to add item to dictionary and print a message that updates with their input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, while-loop

I'm a beginner learning Python and I'm stuck on this problem:

Ask the user to add one topping to the pizza. Modify the dictionary to have that item. Print out every topping the pizza contains, such as: **This pizza contains Topping 1,Topping 2...** and include the topping that the user added.

Given example of dictionary:

```
toppings = {‘pepperoni’:True,’olives':False,'pineapple':True,
‘sausage’:False,’jalapenos’:False}
```

This is what I have so far for the solution:

```
toppings= {'pepperoni':True, 'olives':False,'pineapple':True,
'sausage':False, 'jalapenos': False}

while True:
    pizza = input("Add one topping to the pizza:" )
    toppings[pizza] = input
    break

    print ("You ordered a pizza with the following toppings: " +  [toppings])

for toppings in pizza ['toppings']:
    print("\t" + topping)
```

Comment: This smells like homework...

Comment: its a practice exam question the professor gave out - I've got a test coming up. I want the print statement to be outside of the while loop, I think? I'm trying to teach myself from "Python: A Crash Course" by Eric Matthes and I'm having a hard time to say the least

Comment: Look into the [dict.update()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method

Comment: You should provide an example input and expected output, so we can see what exactly your trying to achieve.

Comment: Ideally, I want the output to state: "Add one topping to the pizza:" and then the user could input "tomatoes," for example, and then it would return, "You ordered a pizza with the following toppings: pepperoni, pineapple, tomatoes" - I'm not sure if I correctly used the terms "input" and "output" by the way, but hopefully the point was conveyed

Comment: I bookmarked the link you gave me, it seems like a lot of useful information so thank you @jk622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I dont understanding why are you using a while loop. Since the program will exit the while loop as long as the user Enter something.

This is a way doing it

```
toppings= {'pepperoni':True, 'olives':False,'pineapple':True,
'sausage':False, 'jalapenos': False}

pizza = input("Add one topping to the pizza:" )
toppings[pizza] = True

print("This pizza contains ",end="")
for topping, topping_status in toppings.items():
    if topping_status:
        print(topping,end=" ")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped a lot. I think I was making it more difficult than it needed to be